# Is it possible to download apk from google play programmatically to PC?

Tags: java, android, python

I'd like to download a lot of apks from google play to PC and install apk on phone for test.

I have seen that http://apk-dl.com/ can download an apk to pc, so is it possible to do the same thing by using java or python or have some code examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Google Play Unofficial [Python API](https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api)  (github)

Using this API you can download APKs using their package name:

```
python download.py com.google.android.gm
```

For finding relevant APKs you can use the search or even parse subcategories

```
python search.py earth
python list.py WEATHER apps_topselling_free
```

Comment: @Marged in config.py there is AUTH_TOKEN  = None, how to get AUTH_TOKEN value?

Comment: Create one from [HERE](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization?hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

You could also scrap http://apk-dl.com to get the apk download link, the steps include to first go to `http://apk-dl.com/{packageName}` and extract the link value in 2 consecutive pages.

A bash example that uses [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/) to download and [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup) to parse HTML would be :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

package=com.facebook.katana

# Download APK 
temp_link=$(curl -s "http://apk-dl.com/$package" | pup ".download-btn .mdl-button attr{href}")
temp2_link=$(curl -s "http://apk-dl.com/$temp_link" | pup ".detail a attr{href}")
dl_link=$(curl -s "$temp2_link" | pup ".contents a attr{href}")

rm -f app.apk
curl -s -o app.apk "http:$dl_link"
```

In Java, the following method return the apk download url :

```java
public static String getApkDownloadUrl(final String packageName) throws IOException {

    Elements data = Jsoup.connect("http://apk-dl.com/" + packageName).get().select(".download-btn .mdl-button");

    if (data.size() > 0) {

        Elements data2 = Jsoup.connect("http://apk-dl.com" + data.attr("href")).get()
                .select(".detail a");

        if (data2.size() > 0) {

            Elements data3 = Jsoup.connect(data2.attr("href")).get()
                    .select(".contents a");

            return (data3.size() > 0) ? "http:" + data3.attr("href") : "";
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

In Python :

```py
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def get_apk_url(package_name): 
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()

    response = opener.open('http://apk-dl.com/' + package_name)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')
    temp_link = soup.find("div",{'class': 'download-btn'}).find("a")["href"]

    response = opener.open('http://apk-dl.com/' + temp_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')
    temp_link2 = soup.find("section",{'class': 'detail'}).find("a")["href"]

    response = opener.open(temp_link2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.read(), 'html.parser')
    temp_link3 = soup.find("div",{'class': 'contents'}).find("a")["href"]

    return "http:" + temp_link3

print(get_apk_url('com.facebook.katana'))
```

Comment: very good! but the third page is protetected with a captcha now

Comment: this is helpful but I think his aim is to write his own code without any third-party package.

Comment: @VinceFR do you know any other way?